# Export Datagridview to existing Excel template

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, export

I have an application (C#.NET, with Windows forms frontend) that a user can add data to. At the end of the process the user can export all the data into an excel file. Currently I am able to create a new excel file and add the datatable in there. But I need to add the data into a specific template document
meaning: I have an existing Excel file with some column headers and fancy colors. I want to add the data I have into the correct cell and save this document under another name. (keeping the template unchanged for further exports).
My understanding of the code of this export method is not good enough to understand what I can change to achieve this, anyone have some tips?

Code:

```cs
private void buttonConfirmExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string userInputFileName = textBoxUserInputFileName.Text;
    if (userInputFileName.Equals(""))
    {
        userInputFileName = "No Title";
    }
    userInputFileName += ".xls";
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);


    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range last = xlWorkSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", last);
    range.Style.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;

    range.Style.VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignTop;


    for (int i = 1; i < advancedDataGridViewCompleteBeoordeling.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
    {
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = advancedDataGridViewCompleteBeoordeling.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
        //xlWorkSheet.Cells.ColumnWidth = 50;

    }


    int imageColumn = advancedDataGridViewCompleteBeoordeling.ColumnCount - 1;


    for (int i = 0; i <= advancedDataGridViewCompleteBeoordeling.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= advancedDataGridViewCompleteBeoordeling.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = advancedDataGridViewCompleteBeoordeling[j, i];
            string text = (cell.Value != null) ? cell.Value.ToString() : "";
            string correctText = text.Replace("*ENTER*", "\n\n");
            if (j == imageColumn)
            {
                try //TODO fix image column
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range) xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1];
                    float Left = (float)((double) oRange.Left);
                    float Top = (float)((double) oRange.Top);
                    const float ImageSize = 128;

                    //TODO change add picture to byte[]
                    xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(text, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Left, Top, ImageSize, ImageSize);
                    //xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(text, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 50, 50, 300, 45);
                    // xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] =
                    Console.WriteLine("row = " + i);
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = correctText;
                    Console.WriteLine(err);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = correctText; //cell.Value;
            }


        }
    }


    //TODO fix saving location on any pc
    try
    {
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(userInputFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);

        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file at 'this pc/documents/'" + userInputFileName);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error.ToString() + "\n\n error code: export 129");

    }

}
```

https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/export-data-to-a-predefined-excel-template-in-c.aspx

I've tried to add something like in this article. But I still don't really understand how to make it work. If it seems like this article will solve all my problems I will give it another shot but I didn't manage it the first time.

Comment: Is it something broke? or what is giving you problems? where is the main problem?

Comment: i need to use an excisting excel file where I insert my data in the correct cells (I also need to be able to chose from 2 different files to insert into, the files will have a different order in column headers, so I need to insert the data in the correct cell still)and save it as a new document

What happens now is that I create a new file and export my datatable as is in there